# Click event does not work properly in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, click

I'm writing a jQuery plugin, but I'm having a problem:

My HTML element

```
<a id="trac"></a>
```

My JS that calls the plugin

```
$('#trac').myplugin();
```

My plugin

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(){
    var $root;
    return this.each(function(){
        $root = $(this);
        $root.live('click',function(){
            console.log('here');
        });
    });
}
```

It happens that "here" is never displayed.
But if I use...

```
 $('#trac').live('click',function(){
     console.log('here');
 });
```

..."here" is displayed.
I don't understand why it is happening because $root and $('#trac') are exactly the same jQuery object.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your plugin loaded before it is called and do you use `document.ready()` arround `$('#trac').myplugin();`?

Comment: What do you want the plugin to do?  Why are you using ".live()"?

Comment: Yes, it is loaded inside a document.ready().

Comment: I had a pause for reflection when I saw the "live" inside the "each" and why you are doing that as the "live" would not normally be multiply applied like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ".live()" function needs a selector, and in your plugin you're not giving it one. The jQuery object you build (`$(this)`) is a valid object but there's no selector string involved.

You could directly bind the handler:

```
  $root.click(function() { ... });
```

To elaborate: you say, "... because $root and $('#trac') are exactly the same."  The problem is that that is not really true. When you build a jQuery object with a selector string, the object keeps that selector string around.  There's no string when you build "$root" from "$(this)".  The ".live()" function operates by creating a handler on the `<body>` element and then testing the target of each event that bubbles up against that selector.

Answer (score 0):

I like the other answer as a "direct" answer to the question but to show some alternate to what you are doing for others I think you can simplfy the plugin as:

```
<div id="mystuff">hi</div>
<div id='answer'>empty</div>

$.fn.myplugin = function() {
    this.live('click', function() {
        $('#answer').text('here');
    });
}
$('#mystuff').myplugin();
```

as shown in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/FgUEB/, thus the "this" gets the selector and you can then attach the "live click" - without the complexity of the .each - which, IF you do it the way you have it (with the selector fixed of course) will put the event on the elements multiple times if it has several - which is implied by the .each you have in your example.

```
jQuery.fn.newMethod = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        alert(typeof this);
    });
};
```

The reference this keyword within the inner function (in the alert) refers to the current HTML element. Since it is NOT a jQuery object it won't have access to the jQuery methods (although, you can wrap it in the jQuery object to get those methods back as jQuery(this).

```
jQuery.fn.newMethod = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        jQuery(this).css({'background-color':'red'});//each inner element
    });
};
```